# WCF Data Services and Upserts

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Services with an entity named Contract.

there is a many to many between Contracts and Quotes : ( * ) Contract <----> ( * ) Quotes

I have a method that adds/remove links between contracts and quotes.

and sometimes I get an updateException because I'm trying to add a link between a Contract and a Quote when the link is already existent.

I want to write a query that adds a link only if the link doesn't exist yet without needing to query the database for the existing links between my contract and quotes.

Is there a way of doing that using Expression Trees ? or Linq ?

At the moment, I do this :

```
void ModifyContract(Contract ctr)
{
    var contractInDb = (from c in service.Contracts.Expand("Quotes")
                       where c.Id == ctr.Id).Single();

    foreach(q in ctr.Quotes)
    {
        if( ! contractInDb.Quotes.Contains(q))
         {
              service.AddLink(ctr,"Quotes", q);
         }
    }

    service.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: When you say that the link already exists, to you mean that it already exists in the database, or in memory?  If you mean the database, there is no way on the client side to know which links are in the database without querying the database...

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question myself for Silverlight [How to do a server-side Insert/Update (Upsert) from Silverlight RIA services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777652/how-to-do-a-server-side-insert-update-upsert-from-silverlight-ria-services)

You either need to check for an existing relationship (then it is just down to how efficient you can make it), or you can put your Upsert functionality into a stored procedure (e.g. sp_UpsertQuote(contractId, quoteId) and call that instead of using SaveChanges().

Comment: Is it not possible to write an Expression Tree that can do all the processing on the server side ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server 2008 **R2** then I would recommend you create a SQL server stored procedure that utilizes ***[Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)***.

If you don't then I would still write a stored procedure to upsert.

The benefit of this is that you don't need to make multiple requests to the Database just to figure out if you need to create or update.

Comment: Is it not possible to write an Expression Tree that can do all the processing on the server side ?

Comment: I would open Sql profiler and look at the query generated. I think that it will make two requests on the same connection.